# Are all servers assigned static IP addresses?

Tags: networking, server

I was learning about IP addresses and I came to know that in the client-server architecture, the servers are typically assigned static IP for the purpose of simplicity in resolving, etc. But do we not run out of IP(I assume IPv4) addresses if every server uses a static IP address?
Btw is it really necessary for the server to use IPv4 address if the client-side of the transaction is done using IPv4?
Correct me if I am completely wrong in understanding the whole thing :)

Comment: Interesting reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_address_exhaustion :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.